# Source/Dot operator error on login. Possibly caused by bad byobu uninstall

Tags: bash, login, bashrc, byobu

I am getting an error message every time I ssh into my box or run `sudo -i`. It looks like this for login:

```
login as: person
chands@ubuntu-server's password:
-bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
chands@ubuntu-server:~$
```

And like this when I execute `sudo -i`:

```
chands@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for chands:
-bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
root@ubuntu-server:~#
```

This error doesn't appear when I launch screen, when I use `sudo` to execute some other commands, when i execute `sudo su` and not even when I `su` into chands from root.

I checked ~/.bashrc for both chands and root and /etc/bash.bashrc but all three of them are the defaults and none of them have any errors with `.` usage.

Also, this error started happening after i removed and purged byobu from my system. I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but that's my point of reference before which everything worked fine.

What could be going wrong here? Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You have to check `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*` and, if exists, `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Try `bash -xl`. The `-l` makes it a login-shell, which is what `ssh` and `sudo -i` will run as well. `-x` turns on debugging mode, making it echo each command before executing it. Should help in narrowing down where the error is.

Comment: @enzotib: It was ~/.profile that was the offending file! And my hunch that it might have something to do with byobu was correct. This was the last line in both mine and root's .profile files: `. $(which byobu-launch)`. Obviously which didn't return anything since byobu-launch didn't exist and thus `.` barfed.

Comment: @geirha: Your suggestion was just as helpful and is a great bit knowledge that I'm sure will come in handy some day. When I ran `bash -xl` I saw that the last line being executed in the login process was just `.` and right before that was `which byobu-launch so I was able to easily pinpoint what was wrong. This combined with enzotib's advice solved the problem!

Comment: someone should provide the answer as a "proper answer" so it can be accepted and this question closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the root cause of this issue was indeed byobu (well actually the lack of byobu). I do not know why but for some reason byobu didn't clean up a line from `~/.profile`.This was the last line of the file: `. $(which byobu-launch)`. Luckily I was able to find this line quite easily and quickly by doing the following (as advised by @enzotib and @geirha):

First I ran `bash -xl` to enter bash as a login shell(`-l`) in debug mode(`-x`). When I ran this I could see what the offending line was. Once I knew what was causing the problem I issued `cat <file> | grep . $(which byobu-launch)` for every file that is executed when bash starts up.

Those files are the following:

1. `~/.bashrc`
2. `/etc/bash.bashrc`
3. `~/.profile`
4. `/etc/profile`
5. `/etc/profile.d/*`
6. `~/.bash_profile`
7. + all others that are included/executed by any of the above files.

Comment: `which` is a command you should never use, especially not in a shell script. For interactive use, it is far superseded by the `type` builtin of the shell. Remember, avoid whichcraft.

Comment: @geirha: FYI, byobu inserted that line itself, it wasn't something I put in.

Comment: Yes, I assumed as much. I just thought it was an important thing to mention. Byobu definitely needs fixing when it adds bugs to a user's .profile. `. byobu-launch` or `command -v byobu-launch >/dev/null && . byobu-launch` would make much more sense to use.